# Single Table Inheritance in rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> I have a problem related to Single Table Inheritance, and I have never used it, can you guys help me?

Deck model

```
name: string
has_many Content
Content has 2 types: Content::ForTerm / Content::ForPhrase
Content::ForTerm has many Term
Content::ForPhrase has many Phrase
```

term model :

```
id, word, meaning, reading
```

phrase model :

```
id, sentence
```

Comment: It's same as an earlier version of rails. please refer this https://devblast.com/b/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model class with class name as Content and two other child class as Term and Phrase which must be inherited from class Content

### syntax would be

```
# app/models/Content.rb
class Content < ApplicationRecord    
  #your code    
end

# app/models/term.rb
class Term < Content    
  #your code    
end

# app/models/phrase.rb
class Phrase < Content    
  #your code    
end
```